# Добавлять к атрибуту в xml, новые элементы

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xml

Расскажите недалекому, пожалуйста, как добавлять новые элементы в xml файл, к определенному атрибуту.
У нас идет форма. В ней мы вписываем Логин, пароль и и выбираем из списка пользователей, к кому мы прикрепим этот логин и пароль.

> Это я к чему. Это логин и пароль от 1С. В комбобоксе находятся
> пользователи программы. У одного пользователя, может быть много
> аккаунтов 1с. И когда юзер заходит в программу, ему в форме выведутся
> только его пользователи.

Вот так выглядит структура xml файла

```
  <Users1CList>
<User1C Mother="Юзер программы 1">
  <USER1C>Логин1С</USER1C>
  <UserPass>Пароль1С</UserPass>
</User1C>
<User1C Mother="Юзер программы 2">
  <USER1C>Логин1С</USER1C>
  <UserPass>Пароль1С</UserPass>
</User1C>
    <User1C Mother="Юзер программы 3">
  <USER1C>Логин1С</USER1C>
  <UserPass>Пароль1С</UserPass>
</User1C>
```

И вот я хочу к Юзеру программы 1, добавить еще один профиль 1С. Не просто, чтобы вниз списка добавлялись новые значения, а мы потом бегали по всему файлу собирали совпадения, а именно к конкретному атрибуту. И выглядело это вот так

```
  <Users1CList>
<User1C Mother="Юзер программы 1">
  <USER1C>Логин1С</USER1C>
  <UserPass>Пароль1С</UserPass>
  <USER1C>Логин1С</USER1C>
  <UserPass>Пароль1С</UserPass>
</User1C>
<User1C Mother="Юзер программы 2">
  <USER1C>Логин1С</USER1C>
  <UserPass>Пароль1С</UserPass>
</User1C>
    <User1C Mother="Юзер программы 3">
  <USER1C>Логин1С</USER1C>
  <UserPass>Пароль1С</UserPass>
</User1C>
```

Форма добавления, выглядит вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мы заполняем поля, добавляем в список и сохраняем его. Я использую сериализацию.

Вот так, выглядит кнопка сохранения

```
        Users1C users1C = new Users1C();
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lvUsers.Items)
        {
            if (item.Tag != null)
            {
                users1C.Users1CList.Add((User1C)item.Tag);
            }
        }
        SerializeXML(users1C);
```

Кнопка добавления в список тоже примитивная

```
 User1C user1C = new User1C(tbUsername.Text, tbNukeCode.Text, ((User)cbUserLogin.SelectedItem).Username);
        Add(user1C);
```

Метод Add

```
ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem(user1C.UserName);
        list.Tag = user1C;

        lvUsers.Items.Add(list);
```

Жду критики, спасибо.

User1C

```
[Serializable]
public class Users1C
{
    public Users1C() { }
    public List<User1C> Users1CList = new List<User1C>() { };
}
[Serializable]
public class User1C
{
    [XmlElement("USER1C")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPass { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Mother")]
    public string UserLogin { get; set; }

    public User1C() { }
    public User1C(string Username, string Userpass, string UserLogin)
    {
        this.UserName = Username;
        this.UserPass = Userpass;
        this.UserLogin = UserLogin;
    }
}
```

Сохранение

```
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Users1C));
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathUser1CFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                xml.Serialize(fs, users1C);
            }
```

Comment: `SerializeXML` - что используется внутри этого метода: `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, что-то ещё? И покажите код модели `User1C`.

Comment: `key="value"` - это **атрибут**. `<name>...</name>` - это **элемент**.

Comment: Дополнил. К чему последний коммент, не понял. Вроде так и написал

Comment: К атрибуту невозможно добавить элемент. Изучите сам XML, из чего он состоит, какие термины используются и т. п.

Comment: Т.е то, что я захотел, невозможно реализовать? Интересно

Comment: Из-за неверной терминологии, которую вы используете - понять вопрос невозможно. Исправьте пост в соответствии с замечаниями из комментариев.

Comment: Все еще ничего не понятно. Есть вопрос, возможно с расплывчатым определением, но так же и есть наглядный пример того, как должен выглядеть результат. В чем проблема понять смысл выражения "к атрибуту добавить новые элементы", я не понимаю. Если человек не добавлял узлы в определенные места xml документа, то к чему вообще отвечать.

Comment: Ещё раз: в **атрибут** невозможно добавить **элемент**! Идите учить XML! Можно в элемент добавить другие элементы и/или атрибуты. ЗЫ: можно использовать следующее выражение: "элемент с определённым атрибутом", "элемент, имеющий атрибут". Если именно это имеется в виду - так и напишите.

Comment: _Жду критики, спасибо._ - И тут же, получив критику: _то к чему вообще отвечать_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Жду критики, спасибо.

На протяжении многих лет я встречаю вопросы по XML, в которых путают **элементы** и **атрибуты**.

Элемент записывается в угловых скобках: `<name>...</name>`.
Атрибут состоит из пары ключ и значение: `key="value"`.
Внутри элемента может быть множество других элементов и атрибутов.

Не путайте базовые понятия, используйте корректные термины XML!

---

`XmlSerializer` никак не использует атрибут `[Serializable]`, поэтому его можно удалить. Чтобы не было путаницы, отмечу: атрибуты языка C# и атрибуты XML - разные вещи.

---

Параметр `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` при записи замените на `FileMode.Create`. В противном случае в файле может получиться некорректный результат, если будет записано меньше информации, чем было раньше.

---

У вас стоит задача в первую очередь найти определённого пользователя.
После того как данные загружены из xml-файла (десериализованы), это можно сделать так:

```
var user = users1C.Users1CList.First(u => u.UserLogin == "login1");
```

Далее нужно добавить новые данные этому пользователю. Это невозможно в рамках вашей модели: юзер имеет лишь одиночные свойства `UserName` и `UserPass`, а нужны коллекции.

Поэтому перепишем код.

---

---

Класс `Users1C` не имеет смысла, т. к. он содержит только одно свойство-список. Его следует удалить и использовать просто список `List<User1C>`

```
public class User1C
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public List<UserInfo> Info { get; set; }

    public User1C() { }
    public User1C(string name, string pass, string login)
    {
        Name = name;
        Info = new List<UserInfo>();
        Info.Add(new UserInfo { Pass = pass, Login = login });
    }
}

public class UserInfo
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
}
```

Это модели классов, которые будем использовать. Обратите внимание на имена свойств: `Name`, `Login`, `Pass` - без приставки `User`, потому что и так понятно, что они относятся к пользователю. Лишний словесный шум не нужен.

При желании, добавьте конструкторы классу `UserInfo`.

Коллекция пользователей - просто список:

```
private List<User1C> _users;
```

---

Сериализатор создаём следующим образом:

```
XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(
    typeof(List<User1C>)
    /*, new XmlRootAttribute("UserC1List")*/
    );
```

И не нужно его создавать локально внутри метода, лучше сделать его полем класса (формы), чтобы был всего один экземпляр.

Уберите комментарий, чтобы задать желаемое имя корневому элементу.

---

Добавление пользователей в коллекцию:

```
_users.Add(new User1C("name1", "pass1", "login1"));
_users.Add(new User1C("name2", "pass2", "login2"));
```

---

Десериализация:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    _users = (List<User1C>)_serializer.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

---

Поиск пользователя по имени:

```
var user = _users.First(u => u.Name == "name1");
user.Info.Add(new UserInfo { Pass = "pass3", Login = "login3" });
```

И добавляем ему новую информацию.

---

Сериализация:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
{
    _serializer.Serialize(fs, _users);
}
```

---

XML будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<UserC1List xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <User1C Name="name1">
    <Info>
      <Login>login1</Login>
      <Pass>pass1</Pass>
    </Info>
    <Info>
      <Login>login3</Login>
      <Pass>pass3</Pass>
    </Info>
  </User1C>
  <User1C Name="name2">
    <Info>
      <Login>login2</Login>
      <Pass>pass2</Pass>
    </Info>
  </User1C>
</UserC1List>
```